# Rails root url with mod_proxy

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, mod-proxy

Rails versions: 3.2
I have an existed PHP site and I would like to add new features in it with Rails.

The final gole is to migrate the entire site to rails, therefore I choose to use mod_proxy to integrate rails by a sub path: /ror

Here's my mod_proxy setting:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /ror http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /ror http://localhost:3000/
```

The problem is, when I tying to use url helper, rails gives the relative path which is wrong.

```
<%= url_for(:action => 'index', :controller => 'travels' %>
```

Gives

```
/travels/
```

And the correct result will be

```
/ror/travels/
```

The idea of url helper and other helper with relative url is good. I intent to use them.
How do I set the correct root path for rails to use in helper?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using rails 4, here is what you may add before proxy declaration:

> ProxyRequests Off
> ProxyPreserveHost On

And add retry=0 to allow rails server to restart

> ProxyPass /ror `http://localhost:3000/ror` retry=0

in config.ru

> map "/ror" do
> run Rails.application
> end
>
> map "/" do
> run Rails.application
> end

in config/application.rb
add this line:

> config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/ror"

Notice that this will direct all url from:

> `http://domain.com/ror` to `http://localhost:3000/ror`

remember to use link_to or root_url to get uri with baseuri /ror